How Physics.SE handles "resource recommendation question"
This post is just a reference, and food for thought.  Maybe we can adapt some of these ideas.

Their policy is described here:


See my answer here for the
rationale behind this policy
Note that this will require some community members to commit to curating the resource recommendations by flagging for post notice
addition, flagging+commenting on bad answers, etc. This can't go
through unless we get enough people who are willing to patrol for
resource recommendation questions and spruce them up to fit policy. If
you wish to help, just say so in a comment below this answer.
I am using the word "resource" instead of "book" here, as this policy can apply to requests for websites as well. Note that reference
requests are different, these usually have one or two answers.

What is a resource recommendation question?
A resource recommendation question is one that asks for a resource
(which can be a book, website, or other resource) to learn a topic
from. It should have the resource-recommendation tag.
This is not the same as a specific-reference question, which
asks for a specific paper in which a derivation or concept is
explained.
What sort of resource recommendation questions are allowed here?
Resource recommendations must ask for descriptive answers. It's not
enough to ask for a list of books that cover topic X — a simple
Amazon search can provide that.
Instead, you should ask for recommendations, which specify:

What the book covers
How it covers it — is it rigorous? Intuitive? How is the writer's style?
What are the prerequisites?

and similar questions.
Actually, this becomes more of a constraint on answers to resource
recommendation questions, which brings us to the next point:
How should I answer a resource recommendation question?
If you wish to answer a resource recommendation question, the answer
should be substantive, and give as much information about the book as
possible. Try to explain the style of the author, as well as listing
the topics it covers well and the topics which it isn't so thorough
with. Try to list the prerequisites too.
Here are some examples that show what good answers to resource
recommendation questions should look like:

Getting started general relativity
Quantum Field Theory from a mathematical point of view
Dark matter references

As a community member, how should I treat resource recommendations?
If you see a rather narrow resource recommendation, see if you can
convert it into a question about the concept the OP really wants to
know, rather than a request for resources that explain the concept.
Such questions are much more useful to the OP and the site in general,
because the explanation is on-site and the reader need not go
elsewhere to learn. So, if a resource recommendation looks directly
answerable with a reasonable-length answer, then convert it to such a
question.
Otherwise, flag the post for moderator attention asking for the
resource recommendation post notice to be applied. Here's the text of
the post notice:

Before answering, please see our policy on resource
recommendation questions. Please write substantial answers that
detail the style, content, and prerequisites of the book, paper or
other resource. Explain the nature of the resource so that readers can
decide which one is best suited for them rather than relying on the
opinions of others. Answers containing only a reference to a book or
paper will be removed!

And finally, if you see answers which are just suggestions of a book
or paper without explanation, flag them so they can be deleted.
Dealing with old recommendation posts
If you come across an old recommendation post, move all of the answers
that are against policy into a community wiki list answer, and give it
the following banner:

This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by the site's policy on resource
recommendation
questions.
This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet
have commentary.

This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note
that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly
discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation
questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**.
This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have
commentary.


